# Show AIX operator panel status

Tags: aix

Is possible to see codes on the operator panel of P5 IBM workstation from console?

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of `showled`?

Comment: I think you can install NetBSD on the given machine...

Comment: showled report nothing,netbsd is not aix and i can use on x86

Comment: Is the system connected to an HMC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Some parts omitted on how to change the system attention indicator after OP clarified that he only wants to see the codes shown on the operator panel data data field.

Yes it is possible to show the status of the system attention indicator. You can either do that via [`diag` command](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/diag.htm) interactively via going to

`=> Task Selection (Diagnostics, Advanced Diagnostics, Service Aids, etc.)

==> Identify and Attention Indicators`

but I find it easier to directly run the command for the two LEDs. Documentation on those binaries is pretty sparse, but can still be found at the [Infocenter under AIX tasks and service aids](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER6/areah/aixserviceaids.htm)

You're looking for usysfault:

> **Fault indicators** This task is only available through a command line interface. It is not available from the diagnostic menu nor from
>   stand-alone diagnostics.
>
> The fault indicators are used to identify a fault with the system.
>   These indicators may be set automatically by hardware, firmware, or
>   diagnostics when a fault is detected in the system.
>
> The System Attention Indicator is turned off when a Log Repair Action
>   is performed. All other Fault Indicators are turned off when the
>   failing unit is repaired or replaced. After a serviceable event is
>   complete, do a System Verification to verify the fix. Also, do a Log
>   Repair Action if the test on the resource was good, and that resource
>   had an entry in the error log.
>
> For additional information concerning the use of these indicators,
>   refer to the system unit service information.
>   **Note:** The AIX command does not allow you to set the fault indicators to the fault state. Use the following command syntax:
>
> ```
> /usr/lpp/diagnostics/bin/usysfault [-s normal] [-l location code | -d
> devicename] /usr/lpp/diagnostics/bin/usysfault [-t]
> Flag 
>    Description
> -s normal Sets the fault indicator to the normal state.
> -l location code Identifies the resource by physical location code.
> -d device name Identifies the resource by device name.
> -t Displays a list of all supported fault indicators by physical location codes.
>    When the command is used without the -s flag, the
>    current state of the indicator is displayed as normal or fault.
>
> When the command is used without the -l or -d flag, the System
> Attention Indicator is used.
>
> Use the -l or -d flags only in systems that have more than one fault
> indicator.
> ```
>
> **Note:** See also the [Identify and system attention indicators](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER6/areah/aixserviceaids.htm%23aixserviceaids__identsa).

So in general you could run e.g. `/usr/lpp/diagnostics/bin/usysfault -s normal` to set the system attention indicator back to normal state again, or `/usr/lpp/diagnostics/bin/usysfault -t` to see a list of available hardware indicators. Although I'm wondering, usually you can either do this easily via an HMC (if you're using one) or it is also automatically done after a part/hardware replacement when you commit the repair action to the log.

So my question would be "*Are you sure that you only want to disable the attention indicator*?"

Comment: I don't ask to disable the attention indicator,only see on console the actually status led,for example,if led say "880394" i want a command for see 880394 on my console.

Comment: You asked initally about the hardware status leds. What you're asking now is the codes on the operator panel. For a standalone machine not attached to an HMC nor running IVM I think that's not possible to the best of my knowledge. Depending how new your machine is, for old P4/P5 and RS/6000 machines the SRC codes are shown on the console so you can see them there during boot. Up to P5 machines you could also display it via the WebSM function panel "Operator panel value".

On newer machines it can only be displayed via the HMC command lsrefcode as it comes from the FSP.

Comment: Yes,i will edited "code of operator panel" is more correct,thanks

Comment: See my previous comment. As you do not provide any information what model/type your physical box is and whether it's managed by an HMC cannot really help you further. Also see the same comment from @Jeff Schaller.